# Рисование на scrollable Canvas

Tags: python, python-3.x, gui, tkinter

Есть приложение-рисовалка.

Пользователь рисует на canvas с возможностью прокрутки (к нему прикреплены скроллбары)

```
from tkinter import *


class GUI:

    def __init__(self):
        root = Tk()
        root.minsize(400, 400)
        root.maxsize(1280, 680)

        frame = Frame(root)
        frame.grid(row=0, column=0)
        frame.pack(fill=BOTH)
        self.canvas = Canvas(frame, bg="grey",
                             width=500, height=500,
                             scrollregion=(0, 0, 5000, 5000))

        self.canvas.bind("<B1-Motion>", self.draw)
        self.canvas.bind("<Button-1>", self.draw)

        self.xscroll = Scrollbar(frame, orient='horizontal', command=self.canvas.xview)
        self.canvas.configure(xscrollcommand=self.xscroll.set)
        self.xscroll.pack(side=BOTTOM, fill=X)

        self.yscroll = Scrollbar(frame, orient='vertical', command=self.canvas.yview)
        self.canvas.configure(yscrollcommand=self.yscroll.set)
        self.yscroll.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)

        self.canvas.pack(side=TOP, fill=BOTH)

        self.cursor_size = 10
        root.mainloop()

    def draw(self, event):
        self.canvas.create_oval(event.x - self.cursor_size, event.y - self.cursor_size,
                                event.x + self.cursor_size, event.y + self.cursor_size,
                                fill='black')

        print(self.xscroll.get()[0])

GUI()
```

Все нормально, если не скроллить, НО если попытаться рисовать не в начале canvas'a а прокрутив дальше - линия рисуется **не под курсором, а в начале canvas'a**.

Как я понял, event.x и event.y - это расстояние от левого верхнего края **окна**, а мне нужно расстояние от левого верхнего края **canvas'a**.

Как, собственно, его получить?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В методе `__init__()` записываем размеры `scrollregion` в `self`:

```
self.scrollregion = (0, 0, 5000, 5000)
self.canvas = Canvas(frame, bg="grey",
                     width=500, height=500,
                     scrollregion=self.scrollregion)
```

Дальше в методе рисования добавляем к `event.x` и `event.y` положения движков скроллбаров домноженные на размеры `scrollregion`:

```
def draw(self, event):
    x = event.x + self.xscroll.get()[0] * self.scrollregion[2]
    y = event.y + self.yscroll.get()[0] * self.scrollregion[3]
    self.canvas.create_oval(x - self.cursor_size, y - self.cursor_size,
                            x + self.cursor_size, y + self.cursor_size,
                            fill='black')
```